# React.js Increment and Decrement counter not mapping correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let me preface that I'm in the process of learning React and I'm still pretty green at this.

I'm going to give the necessary parts of the code:

I have built a counter with increment and decrement buttons that are utilized by ways of state, they work just fine until I introduce and array and map over it.  Then things start to break down.  I know my code is wrong, I know there's something amiss however I'm completely ignorant as to what to even look for.

In my `counting.js` I have:

```
    const players = [
  {
    name: "Jon Smith",
    score: 10,
    id: 1,
  },
  {
    name: "Jon Doe",
    score: 40,
    id: 2,
  },
  {
    name: "John Ham",
    score: 30,
    id: 3,
  },
];
```

Which I have mapped in here:

```
    class Counting extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
                  count: 0,
                  nameof: 'Full Name',
                  }

    this.incrementCount = this.incrementCount.bind(this)
    this.decrementCount = this.decrementCount.bind(this)
  }


  incrementCount(e) {
    this.setState({
      count: (this.state.count + 1),
    })
  }

  decrementCount(e) {
    this.setState({
      count: (this.state.count - 1),
    })
  }



  render() {
    const listPlayers = players.map((players) =>
      <Counter
        key={players.id}
        incrementCount={this.incrementCount}
        decrementCount={this.decrementCount}
        nameof={players.name}
        count={players.score}
      />
    );

    return (
     <div className="wrap">

  <Titles header="Counter" subhead="A setState() project" subtitle="this will change" />
    <h3>This doesn't work correctly</h3>
   <ul>{listPlayers}</ul>
  <ScoreList>
    <h3> works</h3>
    <li>
      <Counter
        incrementCount={this.incrementCount}
        decrementCount={this.decrementCount}
        nameof={this.state.nameof}
        count={this.state.count}
      />
    </li>
    <li>
      <Counter
        incrementCount={this.incrementCount}
        decrementCount={this.decrementCount}
        nameof={this.state.nameof}
        count={this.state.count}
      />
    </li>
  </ScoreList>
     </div>
   )
 }

}
```

I have imported my `Counter.js`which is comprised of:

```
    class Counter extends Component {
  render() {
    const { count } = this.props
    const { decrementCount } = this.props
    const { incrementCount } = this.props
    const { nameof } = this.props

    return (
      <div>
        <CountCell>
          <Row style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
                <Col>
                  <CountButton
                    onClick={incrementCount}>
                    <Icon
                      name="icon" className="fa fa-plus score-icon"
                    />
                  </CountButton>
                </Col>
                <Col >
                  <ScoreName>{nameof}</ScoreName>
                </Col>
                <Col >
                  <Score>{count}</Score>
                </Col>
                <Col>
                  <CountButton
                    onClick={decrementCount}>
                    <Icon
                      name="icon" className="fa fa-minus score-icon"
                    />
                  </CountButton>
                </Col>
              </Row>

        </CountCell>
      </div>


    )
  }
}
```

So the increment and decrement buttons are only working globally and only for my static `<li>`, not my ones generated from the array.  If I'm making any sense at all, how do I individually map my inc/dec buttons to each `<li>` and not globally?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you seeing an error? What is the specific behaviour you're seeing?

Comment: when I click the increment and decrement buttons on `const listPlayers = players.map((players) =>
      <Counter
        key={players.id}
        incrementCount={this.incrementCount}
        decrementCount={this.decrementCount}
        nameof={players.name}
        count={players.score}
      />
    );`

nothing happens, the names are mapped over just fine but I can't + or - the score

Comment: I'm not sure if that makes sense or not

Comment: @christopher, if needed you can check out what I deployed at this https://jabbascrypt.com/projectpages/counting .  Click the + and - buttons and you'll see what I'm talking about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep the state also be an array of objects, each storing data for a corresponding user

```
class Counting extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
                  countInfo: []

                  }

    this.incrementCount = this.incrementCount.bind(this)
    this.decrementCount = this.decrementCount.bind(this)
  }


  incrementCount(index) {
    var countInfo = [...this.state.countInfo];
    if(countInfo[index]) {
        countInfo[index].count = countInfo[index].count + 1
        countInfo[index].nameOf = players[index].name
    }
    else {
       countInfo[index] = {count: 1, nameOf: players[index].name}
    }
    this.setState({
      countInfo
    })
  }

  decrementCount(index) {
    var countInfo = [...this.state.countInfo];
    if(countInfo[index]) {
        countInfo[index].count = countInfo[index].count - 1
        countInfo[index].nameOf = players[index].name
    }
    else {
       countInfo[index] = {count: -1, nameOf: players[index].name}
    }
    this.setState({
      countInfo
    })
  }



  render() {
    const listPlayers = players.map((players, index) =>
      <Counter
        key={players.id}
        incrementCount={() => this.incrementCount(index)}
        decrementCount={() => this.decrementCount(index)}
        nameof={players.name}
        count={players.score}
      />
    );

    return (
     <div className="wrap">

  <Titles header="Counter" subhead="A setState() project" subtitle="this will change" />
    <h3>This doesn't work correctly</h3>
   <ul>{listPlayers}</ul>
```

Comment: ok I followed what you posted here however when I press the inc/dec (+/-) buttons it does not affect the `count={players.score}`

Comment: No it doesnt change the players info but the state array, use `count={this.state.countInfo[index].count || 0}`

Comment: I get an error when I add it in here `<Counter
        key={players.id}
        incrementCount={() => this.incrementCount(index)}
        decrementCount={() => this.decrementCount(index)}
        nameof={players.name}
        count={this.state.countInfo[index].count || 0}
      />`

Comment: oh ok , `count={this.state.countInfo[index]? this.state.countInfo[index].count : 0}` that was because initially `this.state.countInfo[index]` is undefined

Comment: thank you so much for being extremely helpful.  that worked!  marking you as answered!

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: I don't fully understand everything that you presented but that's ok, I can learn from it and keep practicing.  thanks again!!!

Comment: Which part you are unclear with, To explain, I had maintained a separate score state for the players since, you cannot share a single one with all of them.